# Would it be possible to read out physical keyboard strokes in node.js?

Tags: linux, node.js, usb, hid

I have a node application which runs on a raspberry pi that keeps track of a bunch of UPnP-players (Sonos), which I would like to be able to control through a physical remote. I have a couple of airmouses, which has small keyboards as well as volume buttons that I would like to use.

I have tried to get a grip on how to read out physical key strokes on a linux machine, and come to the conclusion that I need to read events from the input device, which in my case would be:

```
/dev/input/by-id/usb-Dell_Dell_QuietKey_Keyboard-event-kbd
```

How to find the device and stuff like that is not a problem, the real issue is how to interpret the data that you read from it.

I know that you would receive a C struct, like this:

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

But I'm not sure how I would go about reading this from node. If I could run an external app that would be triggered from pre-defined keystrokes, and then invoke an HTTP-request against my node, that would be my second option, a python script or some native daemon. I have however looked at some hotkey-daemons, but none of them worked.

If would of course be nice if I could contain it within node somehow.

EDIT: So I did some testing, and made a simple snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var buffer = new Buffer(16);

fs.open('/dev/input/by-id/usb-HJT_Air_Mouse-event-kbd', 'r', function (err, fd) {
    while (true) {
        fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, 16, null);
        console.log(buffer)
    }
});
```

This outputs something like this (for space):

```
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 ab cf 03 00 04 00 04 00 2c 00 07 00>
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 c3 cf 03 00 01 00 39 00 01 00 00 00>
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 cb cf 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 ba 40 06 00 04 00 04 00 2c 00 07 00>
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 cd 40 06 00 01 00 39 00 00 00 00 00>
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 d2 40 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00>
```

I realize that the first four bytes are some sort of timestamp, and the following 3 bytes could be something like a micro/millisecond thing.

Another odd thing is that not all keypresses produces output, but a subsequent press might sent twice as much data, and most of the time it starts blasting out data which would stop after subsequent keypresses (or after about 20 seconds or so). I'm not really sure how to interpret that. I have tried to read the source for this daemon https://github.com/baskerville/shkd/blob/master but C is not my strongest language and I can't identify how he handles it (or if it should even be handled). And that daemon didn't even work for me (compiled it on a raspberry pi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's have a look at that struct.

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

A `struct timeval` has this structure:

```
struct timeval
  {
    __time_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
    __suseconds_t tv_usec;      /* Microseconds.  */
  };
```

The definition of those time types are

```
typedef signed long time_t;
typedef signed long suseconds_t;
```

A `signed long` is 4 bytes (well, not if you just follow the spec, but in practice, it is), so the first 8 bytes are a typestamp. Next, you have a type and a code. Both are `short`, so in practice, they're 2 bytes each. Now there's just the value left, and that's an int again, which will be four bytes. Also, a compiler could theoretically add padding between the fields here, but I'm pretty sure he won't.

So, first chop the bytes you've read into chunks of `4+4+2+2+4=16` bytes. Each of those chunks is an event. This fits your sample data. Next, extract the values from the buffer (as little endian values because you're on an ARM system – on a normal PC, you'd need big endian) and interpret the values. For instructions on how to do that, read http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt. The values of the constants aren't written down there, but you can usually find those using `grep -R NAME_OF_CONSTANT /usr/include`.

Let's chop up

```
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 ab cf 03 00 04 00 04 00 2c 00 07 00>
```

as an example.

```
<Buffer a4 3e 5b 51 ab cf 03 00 04 00 04 00 2c 00 07 00>
       |   tv_sec  |  tv_usec  |type |code |   value   |
```

`tv_sec` in hex is `0x515b3ea4` (reversed order because it's little endian), which is `1364934308` in decimal. A simple unix time converter reports that this means `02.04.2013 - 22:25:08`. Looks good!

`tv_usec` is `0x0003cfab=249771`, so actually, the event happened `249771` microseconds after that time.

Type is `0x0004=4`. `/usr/include/linux/input.h` tells us that this is a `EV_MSC`.

Given the type, we can also see the the code, `0x0004=4`, means `MSC_SCAN`.

The value is `0x0007002c`. Turns up nowhere in `input.h`. Hmm.

Comment: Thank you, I have found the constants here: http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/uapi/linux/input.h and I came to a similar conclusion as you regarding size. However, the repeated events is a mystery to me, as well as if I filter out everything that isn't type = 1 and value = 0, I usually get the corresponding keycode, but it misses a lot of strokes. Any idea?

Comment: @jishi: Do the keys appear in a normal console or so? It might be that your keyboard just has a dead battery or so. :D

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I can safely ignore the MSC_SCAN entries. And about the repeated codes, seems like it's the airmouse acting up, I can't replicate the behavior on my wired Dell keyboard. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is fs.createReadStream, so you can install some event handlers.

You can parse input events into structs by using the Buffer.readX routines:

```
  var i = 0;
  while((buf.length-i) >= 16) {
     var event = {
        tssec:   buf.readUInt32LE(i+0),
        tsusec:  buf.readUInt32LE(i+4),
        type:    buf.readUInt16LE(i+8),
        code:    buf.readUInt16LE(i+10),
        value:   buf.readUInt32LE(i+12)
     };
     i += 16;
  }
```