# NodeJS Read stdin from background process

Tags: node.js, stdin, hid

I have a node process running under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as a service (it has a configuration file under /etc/init). The system runs on a headless x86 routerboard to which a barcode reader is connected. What I need to do is be able to read the input from the barcode reader (which behaves like a USB keyboard for all intents and purposes) so that it can be sent to a remote node for processing, but I'd like to avoid having to parse raw HID input.

Right now I'm using `node-hid` but the solution is temporary since I don't know how to parse the incoming data buffer - I have been able to recognize a pattern and map it in a hashtable so that when I receive, say,

```
02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
02 00 03 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I know I have read a 'C' from a Code39 barcode, but this is not portable and, quite frankly, it's so dirty that I'm almost ashamed of it.

What I do know, though, is that the operating system is perfectly able to decode the input it receives from the barcode reader: I can use it to provide standard `stdin` input when the process is in the foreground, using

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('data', function(input) { ... });
```

I can happily read whatever comes from the barcode reader. This, of course, doesn't work when the process runs in the background, so my question is: is there a way to capture the stdin buffer so that it can be read from a NodeJS process running in the background?

Bonus question: if what I'm asking is not possible, can someone point me to a reasonable reference/documentation that can allow me to decipher the HID input I'm receiving (`node-hid` provides only the data buffer) so that I can at least write a portable, generic function to decode it? I'm sure it has already been done, I'd like to avoid having to rediscover hot water :)

Comment: To answer your question I need to know how the background process gives output. You can try to redirect the output of the process to your node program.

Comment: For the other part I am not sure if all hardware interfaces send back same signals. You can use the info given here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742172/would-it-be-possible-to-read-out-physical-keyboard-strokes-in-node-js

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language and sometimes I express myself incorrectly. What I meant to say is that the NodeJS process IS the background process, and I need to capture whatever is entered from the keyboard/barcode reader (stdin) and redirect it to the NodeJS process that is running in the background. Thanks for link, I'll take a look at it!

Comment: @juandemarco do you eventually know if it is possible to read input from a node run in background?