# Node js incoming tls socket closing when run in background or service

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-ec2, tls1.2, systemd

I have a node js server.js I run on a EC2 instance (ubuntu). This server opens a TLS socket connection to a third party streaming API. When executed in the foreground it runs as expected (ie socket connects and stays open receiving data or heartbeat).

However, I would like to run it in the background so it continues running when I disconnect my shell. I have tried running the following commands, all of which run the script, receive a socket connection message and within 30ms immediately close the socket (.on('end'...)):

```
node server.js &
node server.js </dev/null
nohup node server.js &
```

I have also tried setting it up in systemd as service to run with systemctl start [service]. All yield the same result.

What am I missing?

TLS code snippet:

```
const port = 443;
const hostname = 'third-party-host.com';
const tls = require('tls');
var body = '';

const options = {
  host: hostname,
  port: port
};

socket = tls.connect(options, () => {
  logger.info('client connected',
              socket.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
  process.stdin.pipe(socket);
  process.stdin.resume();
})

.setEncoding('utf8')

var body = '';
socket.on('data', function(chunk) {
  if (chunk.slice(-2) == "\r\n"){
    body += chunk.toString();
    logger.verbose(body);
    ...
    body = '';
  } else {
    body += chunk.toString();
  }
})

socket.on('end', function() {
    logger.warn("Socket closed");
});
```

**UPDATED:**

Could the issue be related to process.stdin not accepting input when running in background?
[Previous issue I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074452/nodejs-read-stdin-from-background-process)

Comment: You will probably get more help at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). That's where I ask my systemd questions, and the answers are usually pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Removing these two lines solved it for me:

```
process.stdin.pipe(socket);
process.stdin.resume();
```